# Client fails to connect ejabberd with SSL on port 5223

Tags: ssl, ejabberd

I configured ejabberd 18.09 to enable SSL on port 5223 with a valid SSL certificate and I can open it on the browser and I receive

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<stream:stream id='16717309979809466549' version='1.0' xml:lang='en'
 xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' xmlns='jabber:client'>
<stream:error>
<not-well-formed xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams'/>
<text xml:lang='en' xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams'>
 syntax error</text>
</stream:error>
</stream:stream>
```

with no SSL error, but I cannot connect with Converse or Smack. I have to say that Converse and Smack works fine without SSL with port 5222.
port 5223 config is:

```
module: ejabberd_c2s
max_stanza_size: 262144
shaper: c2s_shaper
access: c2s
tls: true
```

Comment: I can login using Tkabber, which still supports 5223+SSL connection. I can also login with Psi+, configuring in the Account Properties -> Connection -> Host 127.0.0.1, Port: 5223, Encrypto Connection: Legacy SSL. Try with those clients, those it work or still fails?

Answer (score 0):

Its a new port that you configured right? 
You enabled `tls:true`
So you need to provide the **authentication options(certificate url)**. only then it will work